# Solving a system of equations with variables in denominator.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

> Solve for $\{x,y,z\}$:
>   \begin{cases}\dfrac1x+\dfrac2y-\dfrac1z=\dfrac43\\\\
> \dfrac2x+\dfrac3y-\dfrac2z=\dfrac53\\\\
> \dfrac3x+\dfrac4y-\dfrac6z=3
> \end{cases}

My attempt: I have tried combining each equation like so:$$\frac {yz+2xz-xy}{xyz}=\frac43$$ for each equation, but I got nowhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you solve for $\frac1x$ and the like, and then just take the inverse?

Comment: I did not do that because apparently I cannot see simple things like that. Thanks for the answer. Helpful.

Comment: You could find useful this:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_to_Solve_It.

Answer (score 2):

Take $x_1=\frac1x, y_1=\frac1y, z_1=\frac1z$